# Set color of embedded base64 encoded svg

Tags: javascript, svg, base64

I have a base64 encoded svg as an  in future i would like to highlight texts and so on.

i have created a js fiddle to show what i mean (and a bit of what i tried):
https://jsfiddle.net/matzschmanski/46eotpgx/
working for normal svg:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".svg")[0].getElementsByTagName('circle')[0].setAttribute("fill", "red");
```

the same for the base 64 version does not work

Is it possible to access and change the svg document with javascript or does the base64 encoding break the ability to tinker with the values?

Comment: decode it, update it, re-encode it.

Comment: @RobertLongson my worst nightmare coming true, thank you for now!